# Calling route from same server causes an infinite loop

Tags: php, api, server, request

**Before starting**

I use Laravel as example, but I actually made a small project with hand-made MVC and the issue is still occuring, so this has nothing to do with the framework.

**Context**

I use `php artisan serve`, which is the equivalent of `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` to boot up my web app. I do not use Apache (might be a hint ?).

The client (human) request the page `/user` through his web browser. Here is how the controller that responds to this endpoint looks like:

*routes.php*

```
<?php
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
?>
```

*UserController.php*

```
<?php
    namspace App\Http\Controller;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\User;

    class UserController {
        public function index( Request $request ) {
            $users = User::all();

            if( $request->wantsJson() ) {
                return response()->json($users, 200);
            }
            else {
                return view('user.index')->with('users', $users);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Nothing wrong on this code, everything works.

I would like to set up a "store" mecanism, where only my api endpoint is responsible of providing the data. So here is the changes:

*api.php*

```
<?php
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
        Route::resource('user', 'UserApiController');
    }); 
?>
```

*UserApiController.php*

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controller;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\User;

    class UserApiController {
        public function index() {
            return response()->json(User::all(), 200);
        }
    }
?>
```

*UserController.php*

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController {
    public function index() {
        return view('user.index')->with('users', User::all());
    }
}
```

?>

**To reproduce the issue**

To do so, correct me if I go on the wrong path, my endpoint /user should request the data from /api/v1/user, and then provide the data to the view and return the Http response. So here is what I modifyied on the `UserController.php`:

*UserController.php*

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controller;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\User;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    class UserController {
        public function index() {
            $client = new Client;

            $response = $client->get(url('/api/v1/user'));

            return view('user.index')->with('users', User::all());
        }
    }
?>
```

For me, the endpoint will receive the request from the client (human), then send a second request to the api endpoint, fetch the json data, parse it (using `$data = $response->getBody()->getContents();` GuzzleHttp method), and then provide it to the view (using `return view('user.index')->with('users', $data);`.

**Issue**

The server actually infinite loop and I do not understand what is failing in the process. Note that calling an api from another server (for example `https://ipapi.co/json` works totally fine).

Can someone give me a hint on what is causing this freeze?

Comment: Seems logical to me. You call the end point, which calls the same end point, which calls the endpoint and so on, forever

Comment: Is that related to the way PHP web server handles concurrent requests? Does this will have the same effect if I use Apache for example?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitively related to the way PHP handles requests. I rooted my project on same location `localhost:8000` by setting Apache configuration `httpd.conf` and it is working, I can make requests across my routes.

If any kind soul could paste here a technical detail on what is happening with my requests on PHP web server...